# How would I go about converting a double to a char* data type in C

Tags: c

Im trying to convert a double to a char* but so far the code I have tried (included below) just results in a segmentation fault. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

```
int main(){

    double ans = 3.41;
    char* ansChar; 
    
    sprintf(ansChar,"%f",ans);
    printf("%s",ansChar);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You must allocate buffer before writing.

Comment: `ansChar` needs to be an *array* of char large enough to hold the string representation of the value (including the string terminator).  A pointer doesn’t store a string, it stores the address of the buffer that stores the string.